# is this function a measure?

Tags: measure-theory

$\mu : \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N}) \rightarrow [0,\infty] \hspace{2mm}$ with $\mu(\emptyset)=0$,  $\hspace{2mm}\mu(A)=\sum _{n\in A} n^2$, $\forall A \not = \emptyset$.

Is it well defined? I think so, since even when the sum diverges It is clear that the image by $\mu$ of any set $A \in \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})$ verifying that is always $\infty$.
Also given $(A_n)_n$ a sequence of disjoint elements in $\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})$, it is verified that $\mu (\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A_{n})=\sum_{m\in \cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A_{n}}m^2=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\sum_{m\in A_{n}}m^2=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \mu(A_n)$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is well defined. As a matter of fact your choice of $n^2$ just has to be positive in the sense that any $f:\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow [0,\infty)$ has the property that $\mu (A)=\sum _{a\in A}f(a)$ is a measure. Notice that another measure that follows this construction is the **counting measure.**